Modeling for a data set that has different number of factors for each row (not binomial)
The modeling issue I'm having is that the categorical variable for each row has different number of factors. If I can reshape the data by products (a,b,c,.....~cost, hoursum, numPod, numDate), so that dependent variable is product type (a,c,b,...) and the rest of numeric values are independent, that can be an option, but which will violate the degree of freedom because it's small data set.(and the 'week' should not be included)
So how should I analyze cost, or what modeling should I use for this data that every row has different number of product factors (Prod1 to Prod6)?

